# How can I access the property outside of the class

Tags: c#

This is where I have my property:

```
public partial class NewProjectForm : Form
{
private string mSchemaPath = string.Empty;
public string SchemaPath
    {
        get
        {
            return mSchemaPath;
        }
        set
        {
            mSchemaPath = value;
        }
    }
private void OkayBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mSchemaPath = SchemaPathTB.Text;
//SchemaPathTb is where I get the path for the schema.
    }
```

I want to have an access to SchemaPath property in the `Form1` class. This is what I did and I keep getting null reference. No exception though, just null.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public void saveProject()
{
NewProject proj = new NewProject();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode root = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "testXml", null);
XmlElement schemaPath = doc.CreateElement("Schema");
schemaPath.SetAttribute("Path", proj.schemaPath);
root.AppendChild(schemaPath);
}
```

Here `proj.schemaPath` is null. I tried to cast (proj)schemaPath and it is still null. Whenever I save the project, schemaPath does not have value.

Comment: `new` creates a *new* instance.

Comment: It can't be null.  It looks like it should be an empty string since that's the default value.  You are expecting proj to be referencing your existing form you see on the screen.  It isn't.  You made a *new* form (which you never showed).  You have to make a reference to your *existing* form.

Comment: also NewProject isn't the same class as  NewProjectForm that you are showing us either

Comment: even if `proj` was a `NewProjectForm`, `proj.schemePath` would be a compiler error because the property name is `SchemaPath`

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out the syntax errors. It is also not null, I was getting an empty string. I think @LarsTech got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public void saveProject()
{
NewProject proj22 = new NewProject(); //Create new with emtry string
proj22.SchemaPath = "cfasf"; //Dow whatever you want to the string
proj = proj22; //Set it equal to the class you havel already played with the string
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode root = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "testXml", null);
XmlElement schemaPath = doc.CreateElement("Schema");
schemaPath.SetAttribute("Path", proj.schemaPath);
root.AppendChild(schemaPath);
}
```

I'm not really getting what you trying to achieve are but...
If you want to open a new form window and get the text from the element on that form you have to just open it first of course, formname.show() ( make sure the button click event happens when you click the button, just put a messagebox there ) and then yes the value of the string should change

Comment: I am trying to achieve the SchemaPath value in the NewProject class. I created a property in the NewProject class, and defined a new instance of NewProject in the Form1 class to get the SchemaPath value. I guess, I was wrong.